# How to make a button bigger by hovering it in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, button

Hello so am looking for how to make a button bigger by hovering it, like alot of professional websites, So I know a very little thing on how to make the transform of it upper by hovering by adding transform translate, but I also want to know how to make it bigger.
Note: I don't really want to make it done by making the font size bigger, cause after I got my answer I maybe do it for a div.
Also am a bit new to coding, sorry if there is better way to describe my question, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this CSS snippet

```
btn:hover{
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

This article on MDN has a neat tool to see what can be done with the transform property [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: I didn't know the answer for my question is that simple , although Thanks so much, keep the good work up !..

Answer (score 1):

You can use :hover & set property directly now.

'transform' is not a must.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

button {
    padding: 1em;
    background: linear-gradient(60deg, rgb(216, 81, 81), rgb(93, 93, 205));
    color: white;
    font-size: large;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

button:hover {
    scale: 1.25;
    translate: 0 -20px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <button>hover me</button>
    </div>
```